# How to apply Javascript in cascading drop down in PHP(no AJAX )

Tags: javascript, php

I am using two drop down lists first for category and second for sub category. I want to use Javascript's onChange(); to fetch the values of sub categories but am not able to make out how to use it in the code. Plz guide.

```
  <th>Category</th>
  <td>
    <select name="category" class="frm" onChange="fun()">

    <?php
      include("data_connect.php");
      $data=mysqli_query($con,"select * from `category`");
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data))
      {
          echo "<option value=".$row['c_id'].">".$row['name']."</option>";
      }
    ?>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Sub-Category</th>
  <td>
    <select name="sub_category" class="frm">

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['sub']))
    {
        include("data_connect.php");
        $data=mysqli_query($con,"select * from `sub_category` where c_id=".$_POST['category']."");
        while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($data))
        {
            echo "<option value=".$row1['s_id'].">".$row1['name']."</option>";
        }
    }
    ?>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You need to either submit a form (and then re-populate your initial selection) or use ajax.  Those are your only options.  Once the page has been rendered, the PHP is done.  PHP runs on the server, HTML and Javascript run in the client.

Comment: @PatrickQ Can I submit the form and retain the first selection that I made in the category drop down without using AJAX?

Comment: You'll need to add some code to handle the re-selection of the submitted value, as previously mentioned, but yes. Basically, if the value of the current option in your loop equals the submitted value, mark that option as selected.

Comment: @PatrickQ could you plz do that code for me? Would be easier to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to ignore for a moment your invalid table structure as I'm not really sure how you're wanting it to look.  I'll just wrap what you have in a form for now so you at least have something to work from.

Also, your sub-category query is open to SQL injection attacks. You should use bound parameters to address this. You can continue to use mysqli to do that, but I personally suggest switching to PDO.

```
<form method="post" id="categoryForm">
  <th>Category</th>
  <td>
    <select name="category" class="frm" onChange="document.getElementById('categoryForm').submit();">

    <?php
      include("data_connect.php");
      $data=mysqli_query($con,"select * from `category`");
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data))
      {
          // check to see if we should re-select this value because it was submitted
          $isSelected = (!empty($_POST['category']) && $_POST['category'] == $row['c_id'] ? " selected" : "");
          echo "<option value='".$row['c_id']."'" . $isSelected . ">".$row['name']."</option>";
      }
    ?>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Sub-Category</th>
  <td>
    <select name="sub_category" class="frm">

    <?php
    // only if we've submitted the main category selection
    if(!empty($_POST['category']))
    {
        // no need to include data_connect.php again, it was already included above
        $data=mysqli_query($con,"select * from `sub_category` where c_id='".$_POST['category']."'");
        while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($data))
        {
            echo "<option value=".$row1['s_id'].">".$row1['name']."</option>";
        }
    }
    ?>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
</form>
```

Comment: Is using `echo"<option value='$rec[c_id]' selected='selected'>".$rec['name']."</option>";` the same as using `$isSelected = (!empty($_POST['category']) && $_POST['category'] == $row['c_id'] ? " selected" : "");
          echo "<option value='".$row['c_id']."'" . $isSelected . ">".$row['name']."</option>";`

Comment: @TimothySmith No.  What you are proposing would mark them all as selected, which isn't really an option.  You need to dynamically mark one as selected based on the value you are submitting.